# how to replace text using a query

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I replace certain text in a field using sql?

Example Table:

```
id               text
-------------------------------
1        hello my name is keven
2        hello my name is steve
3        hi my name is sam
```

How would I replace `hello` with `hi` in the field `text` while leaving the remaining text untouched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to search and replace in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421227/sql-to-search-and-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET `text` = REPLACE(`text`, 'hello', 'hi')
```

Answer (score 1):

as seen in this [article](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/)

```
update TABLE_NAME set 
FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, REPLACE(text,'hello','hi') AS text from table;
```

It's somewhat database dependent,  but that should work on most databases.